# I can't get all the data from an xml file with php

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I can get the data from the xml apart from all the <Item> data. The code below only gets the data for the last one.  I thought the foreach would get it for each of them but it doesn't seem to.

```
<magic5Out version="2.1.0">
<Report customerPK="Survey_2" locationPK="229" userId="2299" template="13600" formDate="2012-04-11T00:00:00" dateTimeStarted="2012-04-11T07:34:04" dateTimeMobileReleased="2012-04-11T07:37:03" currentStatus="5" reportGuid="b174d011-77bb-4882-b87e-a2c60bdf265d">
    <Results>
        <Item itemPK="SurveyTab_9">
            <q1 listEntry="1.8m" listEntryId="239107"/>
            <q1Comments text=""/>
            <q2 listEntry="Green" listEntryId="239113"/>
            <q2Comments text=""/>
            <item_comments text="test"/>
        </Item>
        <Item itemPK="SurveyTab_24">
            <q1 listEntry="2.2m" listEntryId="239108"/>
            <q1Comments text=""/>
            <q2 listEntry="Silver" listEntryId="239112"/>
            <q2Comments text=""/>
            <item_comments text=""/>
        </Item>
        <Item itemPK="SurveyTab_10">
            <q1 listEntry="3.0m" listEntryId="239110"/>
            <q1Comments text=""/>
            <q2 listEntry="White" listEntryId="239111"/>
            <q2Comments text=""/>
            <item_comments text="No feed"/>
        </Item>
        <Item itemPK="SurveyTab_23">
            <q1 listEntry="2.2m" listEntryId="239108"/>
            <q1Comments text=""/>
            <q2 listEntry="Green" listEntryId="239113"/>
            <q2Comments text=""/>
            <item_comments text=""/>
        </Item>
    <surveyorComments0 text="testing"/>
    <surveyorName text="NICK"/>
    <surveyorSig opFile="D:\Sites\WebApp_eden\Output\2100\XMLSurvey\Attachments\1cf582f9-776c-472e-b8ce-877a51fae5e1.png"/>
    </Results>
</Report>
</magic5Out>
```

here's the php I'm using:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file); 
/* more code here that works OK */
foreach($xml->Report->Results->Item as $tab) {
    $tab_name = (string) $tab['itemPK'];
    $q1_result =  $tab->q1['listEntry'];
    $q2_result =  $tab->q2['listEntry'];  etc.
    $q1_comment =  escape_data($tab->q1Comments['text']);
    $q2_comment =  escape_data($tab->q2Comments['text']);
    $item_comment = escape_data($tab->item_comments['text']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make a loop and define a variable then you have in your case the last value from the loop in your variable.

You overwrite your variable everytime.

```
foreach($xml->Report->Results->Item as $tab) {
    $tab_name[] = (string) $tab['itemPK'];
    $q1_result[] =  $tab->q1['listEntry'];
    $q2_result[] =  $tab->q2['listEntry'];  etc.
    $q1_comment[] =  escape_data($tab->q1Comments['text']);
    $q2_comment[] =  escape_data($tab->q2Comments['text']);
    $item_comment[] = escape_data($tab->item_comments['text']);
}
```

try something like this. Then you have an array with all the values.

Comment: Thanks Stony, I've tried this but as before it is only getting the values from the first Item but stores them in arrays rather than as strings, i.e there is only one value in each array.  (if it was overwriting them I would have expected it to end up with the values from the last Item)

Comment: Very strange. I have tried it with your XML and i got all elements. Have you checked your log?

Comment: I'm mystified, but it's working with my original code now! There were no errors logged - it just didn't either loop through all the instances of Item, or, as you suggested, overwrote them.  Too busy catching up with the job to investigate further once it worked, so it will remain a mystery

Answer (score 0):

There must have been something elsewhere in the code that was screwing this up - I tried a load of other things and eventually reverted to the php I posted above and it worked this time.  Hope it was only my own time I wasted on this.